# how to interact with a drop down menu using python and selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

Here is the element from the webpage which I am trying to interact with:

```
<select class="experiment-enable-disable" tabindex="6" jsdisplay="enabled !== undefined" jsvalues=".internal_name:internal_name; aria-labelledby:internal_name + '_name'" jstcache="8" aria-labelledby="enable-experimental-web-platform-features_name">
    <option jsvalues=".selected:!enabled; data-default:!enabled ? 1 : 0" value="disabled" jstcache="15" data-default="1">Disabled</option>
    <option jsvalues=".selected:enabled; data-default: enabled ? 1 : 0" value="enabled" jstcache="16" data-default="0">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code I used to select it:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_class_name("experiment-enable-disable")
```

Now when I try to interact with it in ways such as 'click' or 'sendkeys' it says *"element not interactable"*.

How do I interact with this drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

The drop down menu might not be loaded by the time you try to interact with it. You can always induce a wait by doing the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("insertwebsitehere")

try:
     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,'xpath')).click()
     print("it's clickable")
except:
     pass
```

EDIT: I would use the XPATH if at all possible. Also `find_element_by_class_name` is deprecated. Instead use `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "insert class name here")` if you want to use the class name instead of the XPATH.

Comment: Unfortunately it's already clickable. I found a work around using send_keys but it doesn't correctly answer the question.

Comment: @DavidO'Donovan you can still use my piece of code to check that it's clickable; after the ```wait``` you can implement for the code to click on the XPATH of the element that you need. For example: ```find_element(By.XPATH, ' ').click()```. You can also implement ```time.sleep()``` to wait for the drop down menu to load. Of course you have to import ```time```.  I'm unsure what your XPATHs are going to be and I hope this helps or clarifies what I was trying to do. Let me know if this was not what you were looking for or have questions